# How to avoid repeating code while using plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I want to produce same type of chart for some combination of data. Currently, I am using `plyr` to split the data and executing some code for each of the combination.

For example, let's say the `dataframe` has company, department, region, and revenue. Here's my pseudocode:

```
     d_ply(dataframe, .(company),  function(df) {
      d_ply(df, .(department),  function(df) {
        d_ply(df, .(region), function(df) {
           bar_chart(df$region, df$revenue)
        })
            bar_chart(df$department, df$revenue)
      })
            bar_chart(df$company, df$revenue)
    })
```

In my real example, I need to do multiple things, and the code is 10 or so lines. Is there a way to avoid repeating the code in each combination, other than creating a function and just passing the proper parameters? I was hoping that there is some magic `plyr` trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy data:

```
d <- data.frame(company=letters[1:26],
                department=sample(letters[1:10],26,replace=TRUE),
                region=sample(letters[1:3],26,replace=TRUE),
                revenue=round(runif(26)*10000))
```

#### Update

I think an explanation of your code is necessary:

```
d_ply(dataframe, .(company),  function(df) { # by company
      d_ply(df, .(department),  function(df) { # by department
        d_ply(df, .(region), function(df) { # by region
           bar_chart(df$region, df$revenue)
           # this part is essentially equal to
           # d_ply(df, .(company,department,region), function(df), plot(df)) 
    })
  bar_chart(df$department, df$revenue)
  # this part is essentially equal 
  # d_ply(df,.(company,department), function(df), fun(df))
  })
 bar_chart(df$company, df$revenue)
 # this part is essentially equal to 
 # d_ply(df,.(company), function(df), fun(df))
})
```

I find your code to be highly unreadable. It could be replaced with:

```
some.fun <- function(df, ...) {
# ...
}

d_ply(d, .(company), function(df) some.fun(df, ...))
d_ply(d, .(company,department), function(df) some.fun(df, ...)) 
d_ply(d, .(company,department,region), function(df) some.fun(df, ...))
```

Comment: maybe, I should clarify my explanation, because if we put the plot command under single d_ply, it would not sum by each category by rolling up, would it? Since it is already split by company, department, region, all the revenue is going to be at that combination level and if we plot company and revenue, it actually wouldn't reflect total by company.

Comment: thanks for the edit and another answer. I think it would lessen some repetition and make the code cleaner.

Comment: I also found that plyr will create an attribute (vars) and store the split variable, so it will be possible to pass the split variable to the function as well.